# No se actualiza mi ventana de PyQt5 despues de realizar cambios

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, design

Estoy con mi primer programa, que es el de conversor de temperatura de °C a °F.

El problema que tengo, es que cuando realizo cambios, no se ven reflejados en la ventana `GUI`; así como se ejecutó la primera vez, asi me sale siempre que realizo cambios a mi ventana en `Qt Designx`.

Tengo la aplicación de `Anaconda Qt Design 5.9.7 Spyder 3.3.2`

Corre sobre Windows 7 de 64 bits

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Espero poder ayudarte. Ya que también soy nuevo en este foro.
Cuando creas una GUI en Qt Creator, esta se guarda con extención ui. Cada cambio que realizas se guardara siempre con ese formato. Lo que debes de hacer es pasar ese archivo ui a uno py mediante esta instruccion en la consola:

pyuic5 NombreArchivo.ui -o NombreArchivo.py

Esto deberás de hacerlo después de los cambios que realizes en tu archivo ui.

Al menos así es como yo he estado haciéndolo. Tal vez haya una mejor solución. Pero esta me ha servido en lo poco que he trabajado en Python y Qt